# jquery .ajax's .done function get done on alert only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This seems a bit strange and i cant get a hold of the situation, apparently i used jquery's .ajax() function to process some script to get some data from the database. The script works fine and data gets returned as accordingly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getevaluationdata.php",
    data: { evaluation_ID: value }
})
.done(function( msg ) { 
    $("#error2").html(msg);
});
```

After the scripts process, it is suppose to populate the data echoed in the script to the div i mentioned, but this does not happen. However, if i write an alert statement before the div population, the div gets populated. meaning:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getevaluationdata.php",
    data: { evaluation_ID: value }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert(msg);
    $("#error2").html(msg);        
});
```

I dont seem to get why this is happening and what I can do to resolve this.
P.S. I have done this before, and this was working correctly before

Comment: All the `alert` would do is change the *timing*. So the problem is elsewhere in your code. If you can boil it down to an [MCVE](/help/mce), we can help you see where.

Comment: might be irrelevant but try with `success` inside `ajax` even though they are same! or keep your `$("#error2").html(msg)` inside `setTimeout` with minimal time

Comment: @T.J the code is fine and otherwise the what i am doing in the div would not have been populated by alert,

Comment: @Rao, tried it with success also, same result :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible #error2 is not on the page yet?, so the alert gives it time? try putting the ajax call in

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getevaluationdata.php",
      data: { evaluation_ID: value }
    }).done(function( msg ){
      $("#error2").html(msg);
    });
});
```

Another thing you can try for reference is using the success callback

```
$.post("getevaluationdata.php",{evaluation_ID:value},function(msg){
    $("#error2").html(msg);
});
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem, moved the ajax call into a function and called it on document.ready....

Comment: @blogger: As I said: Timing, in code not in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes ofcourse, i understood now, sorry for that